# Half sliced div triangle in css? using border radius

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this type of Design

[image]

Where on the left corner there's a div container white background color

and behind of that container there's an image

I'm not sure where to start using css.

But I believe this is possible using css only.

I have this html codes

```
 <div style="background: url("../image.jpg"); background-size:cover; background-repeat: none; ">
    <div class="half-triangle"></div>

 
 </div>
```

Comment: did you try clip-path?
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);

Comment: This gives me an idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use transform: rotate() and overflow: hidden on the outer element

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

.text {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(50% + 50px);
  height: calc(100% + 200px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-100px, -100px);
}

.inner {
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="inner">
      Some text here..
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</div>
```

[See solution on codepen](https://codepen.io/tihu/pen/XWgMNoX)